# mysql possible to select count(distinct(id) where col = 'value')?

Tags: mysql

I'm using car makes as an example, which fits my situation nicely.

Example query I have now, that gives a simple count per state:

```
SELECT
  state as State,
  count(distinct(idnumber)) as Total
FROM
  database.table
WHERE
  make IN('honda', 'toyota', 'subaru')
GROUP BY
  state
ORDER BY
  state
```

Note that this would give me the count for each of the car makes, excluding things like Ford, Chevy, etc. The list of makes would be every make.

Is there a way I can break that down to give me the count of each make by state without resorting to a sub-query? In my head it would be like having a where statement in the count(distinct(idnumber)) select, but I'm not sure that's possible.

Here's what is in my head:

```
SELECT
  state as State,
  count(distinct(idnumber)) as Total_State,
  (count(distinct(idnumber)) WHERE make = 'honda') as Total_Honda
WHERE
  make IN('honda', 'toyota', 'subaru')
GROUP BY
  state
ORDER BY
  state
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add multiple columns to your group by:

```
GROUP BY
  state, make
```

I may misunderstand your question, but you can group along two columns, so you will get the number of fords made in CA and hondas made in CA etc

To be explicit, your query would be this:

```
SELECT
  state as State,
  count(distinct(idnumber)) as Total,
  make as Make
FROM
  database.table
WHERE
  make IN('honda', 'toyota', 'subaru')
GROUP BY
  state, make
ORDER BY
  state
```

Just as a fun test, I did this:

```
create table `cars` (
`id` int(11),
`make` varchar(255),
`state` varchar(255)
);


insert into cars(id, make, state) values 
     (1, 'honda', 'ca'), (2, 'honda', 'ca'), (3, 'toyota', 'ca'), 
     (4, 'toyota', 'az'), (5, 'toyota', 'az'), (6, 'honda', 'az');


SELECT state as State, count(id) as Total, make as Make
FROM cars
WHERE make IN('honda', 'toyota', 'subaru')
GROUP BY state, make
ORDER BY state
```

And got back:

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| State | Total | Make   |
+-------+-------+--------+
| az    |     1 | honda  |
| az    |     2 | toyota |
| ca    |     2 | honda  |
| ca    |     1 | toyota |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Which is what I expected. Is that what you were thinking?

Comment: Sort of. Ideally I'd get back 50 rows (1 for each state), with a column for the state name, total in state, and a total for each make in the state. If that makes sense.

Comment: Okay, I see. Is your idnumber really not-unique? If you need that distinct(idnumber) that complicates things. If there are no duplicate ids, then you could do a trick with sum / if: `select state, sum(if(make='honda', 1, 0)) as HondaCount, sum(if(make='toyota', 1, 0)) as ToyotaCount from cars where make in('honda', 'toyota') group by state;`

Comment: If you do need that distinct(idnumber) then I don't know of any way around the subquery. (this would work: `select state, sum(if(t.make='honda', 1, 0)) as HondaCount, sum(if(t.make='toyota', 1, 0)) as ToyotaCount from (select distinct(id), state, make from cars) t group by state;`) However, I wouldn't shy away from *this particular* subquery for performance reasons. Subqueries are evil in mysql in certain circumstances, but I don't think this is one of them (more of a subtable than a subquery)

Comment: I think this is very, very close. The idnumber is unique, however it's not unique to the makes. (it's essentially an address identifier, where there can be multiple makes per address). I'll have to do some looking to see if that will work for this case. Thank you! :)

Comment: Glad to help, these are fun. Quick note -- if you idnumber is unique to make, or even less restrictively to the pair of (make,state) then the query will be fine. The problem would be double counting id=1, make='honda', state='ca'... or something